# ASP.Net DI using a class within a controller without instantiate that class within that controller

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have my "appsettings.json" file content

```
{
 "Logging": {
 "IncludeScopes": false,
 "LogLevel": {
 "Default": "Debug",
 "System": "Information",
 "Microsoft": "Information"
 }
},
 "appData": {
 "applicationDeveloper": "El Bayames"
 }
}
```

And a class that read from appsettings and more

```
public class learningDIGlobalVariables
{
    private String _applicationDeveloper;
    private String _webRootFolderPath;

    public String applicationDeveloper
    {
        get
        {
            return _applicationDeveloper;
        }
    }
    public String webRootFolderPath
    {
        get
        {
            return _webRootFolderPath;
        }
    }

    public learningDIGlobalVariables(IConfigurationRoot auxConfRoot, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _applicationDeveloper = auxConfRoot["appData:applicationDeveloper"];
        _webRootFolderPath = hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    }
}
```

And within the settings container I have

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(Configuration);
    }
```

Within the controller I have

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private learningDIGlobalVariables _learningDIGlobalVariables;
    public HomeController(IConfigurationRoot auxConfRoot, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _learningDIGlobalVariables = new learningDIGlobalVariables(auxConfRoot, hostingEnvironment);
    }
}
```

How do I use that class "learningDIGlobalVariables" within the controller without instantiate it?. Doesn't that class get instantiated by the framework?. If I have to add that class to the Services, How can I do it and use it latter on?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to instantiate the calss than you can make the it static, remove the constructor and add a SetGlobals method:

```
public class learningDIGlobalVariables
{
    public static SetGlobals(IConfigurationRoot auxConfRoot, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _applicationDeveloper = auxConfRoot["appData:applicationDeveloper"];
        _webRootFolderPath = hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    }
}
```

In your startup, in the Configure function you can setup your globals:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(Configuration);
    learningDIGlobalVariables.SetGlobals(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IConfigurationRoot>(), env);
}
```

Comment: And, what about the controller, how to use it within the controller?

Comment: It's public class so you can use the way you are using it right now, other than you don't have to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simply POCO to represent your JSON config.

```
public class AppSetting
{
  public AppData AppData {set;get;}
}
public class AppData
{
   public string ApplicationDeveloper { set;get;}
}
```

Now in the Startup.cs class `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
```

Now in your controller, you will use constructor injection. You do not need to new up any object here. The framework will inject the dependency for you.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IOptions<AppSetting> _settings;

    public HomeController(IOptions<AppSetting> settings)
    {
        this._settings= settings;
    }
}
```

Inside the controller, you can use `this._settings.Value.AppData.ApplicationDeveloper` to get the value you set in your json.

Comment: Got this message: ArgumentException: Type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[learningDI.AppSetting]' does not have a default constructor